# Automatically Finishing Parenthesis In IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle, parentheses

I searched for this for a bit and having not found anything (and not knowing exactly what to search for -_-) I've decided to simply ask the question myself.

It seems like it's a silly question, but It's been bugging me since I first started using IDLE.  I really enjoy using IDLE, but one problem I've had with it is that whenever I type parenthesis (or whatever these [] things are called) It doesn't automatically close them (I type (, and the program knows I need a ), and puts my cursor between the two).  I know, it seems really lazy, but I'm used to using other IDEs for other languages and those tend to have this feature built into them, so I'll often times get silly errors involving unclosed parenthesis.

I guess all I'm asking is if there's any way to apply this feature to IDLE, or if there's alternatives that are similar to IDLE that have this feature built in.

Answer (score 0):

Currently IDLE does not have [this feature](http://bugs.python.org/issue18875).

But many others do, including:

- [NinjaIDE](http://ninja-ide.org/)
- Spyder
- PyDev for Eclipse
- PyCharm
- Komodo IDE
- . . .